# How can you make a method call whenever GridView Sorts?

Tags: c#, datagridview

So what I want to do is allow AutoSorting that's built into GridView, but whenever autosort happens, for it to call a method (`recolor();`) to recolor the results appropriately. Probably an easy question, but I don't see any easy way to do it.

It is a .net form (a .dll I'm using with another application), I have not attempted any code yet, as I don't want to break what I already have set up.

EDIT ANSWER

So, I figured it out in the designer I should have put:

```
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick);
```

And then in the form this will work :

```
     private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            recolor();
        }
```

Comment: asp.net? winforms? WPF? got any code that you have attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Call `recolor()` in the event `GridView.OnSorting`.  See: [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onsorting.aspx).

Comment: I saw that, but what I'm getting is an error saying the namespace name 'GridViewSortEventArgs' could not be found, and I'm assuming it needs to be added to the form designer for it to work properly, but I have not found what I need to add.

Comment: Add to the codebehind file: `using GridViewSortEventArgs;` or whatever other namespace is needed.  You may also have to add it to your project references.